# IIS URL rewrite rule problems with non-English characters

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config, special-characters

I have problems with getting my IIS URL Rewrite 2 rules to work with non-English (Swedish) characters (å ä ö). I'm on Windows Server 2012 R2 (IIS 8.5).

This rule works well with English characters:

```
<rule name="RedirectSubWebKeepURI" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">    
    <match url="^department/lawyers/(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/section/lawyers/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

But assume I would spell "lawyers" as "låwyers" (not a real word!), how can I get it to work?

Neither of the examples below work:

```
<match url="^department/låwyers/(.*)" />          [real character]
<match url="^department/l%C3%A5wyers/(.*)" />     [URL encoded 'å']
```

What am I missing? [This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103306/how-to-handle-special-characters-in-web-config-rewrite-rule) says you have to use the `{UNENCODED_URL}` variable, but does that mean I have to match all URL:s with `".*"` and move the actual matching logic to a condition instead? If so, I can't really figure out how my rule should be rewritten accordingly...

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using internal `UrlEncode{}` like this:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="/section/lawyers/{UrlEncode:{R:1}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks. But will this really help when the problematic character is in the URL text "lawyers" (for example as "låwyers"), i.e. outside {UrlEncode:{R:1}}?  
  

`<action type="Redirect" url="/section/låwyers/{UrlEncode:{R:1}}" />`