# ASP.NET Core Web API url parameters encoded in controller in .NET Core, .NET 6, .NET 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, .net-7.0

What is the right approach for url attributes decoding from HTTP GET requests like:

```
Get /reports/{categories}/date/{date}

[Route("reports/{categories}/date/{date}")]
public IEnumerable<Report> GetReports(string categories, string date)
```

`Categories` is something like `Category1\SubCategory`, it contains a backslash.

From Swagger, I am getting: `Category1\\SubCategory`

From a third-party client, I get: `Category1%5CSubCategory`

Swagger for some reason adds additional backslashes for escaping and third-party client is doing url encoding.

Is there a setting in ASP.NET Core 6, 7 to control the behaviour of parameters regarding special character and encoding?

Comment: Anything is good if it works. What is your problem?  Do you have any error?

Comment: Since this is about an **URL** in your code, I would expect that **URL encoding** (like in your third-party client) is the proper way to go.

Comment: Issue is the one already raised long time ago but never fixed, might be in .net 8: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11544

I can manually HttpUtility.UrlDecode SubCategory but Framework should be handling this. Application is ported to  .Net 7 and Kastrel from IIS where it used to have rules in web.config for handling special characters. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103306/how-to-handle-special-characters-in-web-config-rewrite-rule

Comment: yes agree with you, but before framework handle it, we can only handle it by code-self